# How flexible are the applications of return in the definition of sequence?

Tags: haskell, monads

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]
sequence []     = return []
sequence (x:xs) = x >>= \v -> sequence xs >>= \vs -> return (v:vs)
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. `m` is a `Monad`. But what if the list contains “different kinds” of monads, that is, different constructor values for type `Monad`?
2. Which `return` can be called? I don’t understand because we have a least two possibilities: `return` when matched against `[]` and `return` when matched against a non-empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. All elements in the list must have the same type, so they're all type `m a` for the same monad `m`.
2. Since the desired type is `m [a]`, the `return` for `m` will be used. If the list monad's `return` were used, `return []` would have type `[[]]`, which isn't the declared result and also doesn't match the type of the second case.

Comment: so, compiler based on returning type of function signature deduces a which return should be called, is it?

Comment: @Gilgamesz It decides based on what it knows about what the type must be. This includes the type signature, but in this case it would still get the same type if the signature were not written because it can tell from the type of the second case. That is if you just had `sequence [] = return []` without a signature and without a second case, you'd get the inferred type `sequence :: Monad m => [a] -> m [b]` and the result could be any monad. But we know that the list contains monadic values and the result of the second case is in the same monad as the elements of the list (because ...

Comment: ... of the use of `>>=`), so we know that `return []` must also be in that monad because both cases need to have the same result type. So even if you did not spell out the signature, you'd get the same type if you wrote down both cases.

Answer (score 1):

While `m` can be any concrete monad, once it's specialised to a concrete monad, all occurrences will be of that concrete type. So if you have `[m a]`, then all values in the list must specialise to the same concrete monad. Therefore your questions don't really make sense.